# What exactly does CREATE UNIQUE do in Cypher for neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

(http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create-unique/)

Am I correct that it could be used to create various relationships between two constant nodes (i.e. there are many relationships between two same nodes) with different values in their properties?

Is it possible to have such a command?

```
Load CSV from ...
MATCH (sender:Wallet {primWallAddr:line[0]}), (receiver:Wallet {primWallAddr:line[1]}) 
CREATE UNIQUE (sender)-[:SendTo{tranHashString:line[2],...uniqueReference:(line[2])}]->(receiver)")
```

Is it possible to use "MERGE" instead of "CREATE UNIQUE" to achieve the same result? 
If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE UNIQUE`, perhaps even preferred. What you need to do is to `MERGE` by uniqueReference like so:

```
Load CSV from ...
MATCH (sender:Wallet {primWallAddr:line[0]}), (receiver:Wallet {primWallAddr:line[1]}) 
MERGE (sender)-[:SendTo{tranHashString:line[2],...uniqueReference:(line[2])}]->(receiver)
```

Slightly more optimized would be `MERGE`on unique reference and set additional properties with `ON CREATE`

```
Load CSV from ...
MATCH (sender:Wallet {primWallAddr:line[0]}), (receiver:Wallet {primWallAddr:line[1]}) 
MERGE (sender)-[s:SendTo{uniqueReference: line[2]]->(receiver)
ON CREATE SET s.tranHashString = line[3]
```

If you wanted to have only one relationship between this sender and receiver and just update its properties you would use:

```
Load CSV from ...
MATCH (sender:Wallet {primWallAddr:line[0]}), (receiver:Wallet {primWallAddr:line[1]}) 
MERGE (sender)-[s:SendTo]->(receiver)
ON CREATE SET s.tranHashString = line[3]
ON MATCH SET s.tranHashString = line[3]
```

Answer to question 1 :

Yes from what I understand you can use `CREATE UNIQUE` in your case, just know that if you want to change any property of the relationship, `CREATE UNIQUE` will create a new relationship and never update existing, which will ruin your ID system.

Comment: Is the answer to my first question "correct"? Just to make sure.

Comment: Thank you. Am I correct that merge should not be used for my purpose? Sorry I don't really understood your last sentence: You seems to say that I should use CREATE UNIQUE and not MERGE if I don't want to update the existing relationships. Then in that sentence you said that I should use MERGE? (I assume that the 2nd query is the optimized version right?)  (BTW, the uniqueReference is actually something like (line[2] + line[3]), if that make any differences. )

Comment: If you will never update your relationship you can use `CREATE`, because you will just create a new relationship each time. When you are doing this periodically and do not want to get duplicate relationships in your database you should use `CREATE UNIQUE` and if you ever want to update your relationship your should use `MERGE`

Comment: So if CREATE or CREATE UNIQUE is used, the relationship could also not be deleted?

Comment: You can always delete a relationship if you `MATCH` it and that is the best practice. If you use `CREATE` it will just create a new relationship and then you will delete it. `CREATE UNIQUE` could possibly work for deleting, but I would not use it, because you might run into same problems as with `CREATE` where you create and delete a relationship in a single query

Comment: Sorry if there is any misunderstanding. I did not ask if I could delete a relationship with CREATE or CREATE UNIQUE, I was asking if the relationships could be deleted if they were created with these two command BEFORE deleting.

Comment: you can always delete anything and everything :)

Comment: When you talked about CREATE UNIQUE, you said "doing this periodically". I am new to neo4j, would you care to explain what do you mean by that? Also am I correct that I should use MERGE for my purpose?

Comment: I meant if you ever imported the same csv twice like today and 3 days after with some updated data, you could use CREATE UNIQUE so that it would import only the new data and not do duplications. I always use MERGE when I am importing instead of CREATE UNIQUE if that answers your question. I find it more useful and it is more used by the community

Comment: Thank you. I just want to make sure.

Comment: What would be the difference between "MERGE on unique reference and set additional properties with ON CREATE" and "MERGE on unique reference and set additional properties without ON CREATE" (i.e. directly SET...) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142110/discussion-between-tomaz-bratanic-and-aqqqq).